# Where can I find mididings?

Tags: repository

I find I am unable to install mididings in ubuntu20. (Studio)
I can't even find it, so what do I need to know?
I have searched software, and enabled all the optional sources.
Jzz

Answer (score 3):

As was stated by [user535733 in the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274456/10616), this package was dropped from Debian and in turn removed during the Focal development cycle.

> The following information after this notice was all obtained from [Debian Bug #814894](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814894) and corresponding title edits.  The aforementioned Debian Bug number was obtained via the [Launchpad Publishing History for the mididings source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mididings/+publishinghistory).

Since 2016, the Package Maintainer in Debian had orphaned mididings and nobody picked it up for ongoing maintaining.  Since that time, additional findings were made about the package:

- Orphaned 3+ years earlier (initial 2016 orphan by maintainer)
- Dead Upstream (means that the upstream project is dead with no maintainers or code updates)
- Low package popularity rating (very few installations in Debian)
- Python 2 Only (EOL / Obsolete / Removed version of Python)

Because of this, it was removed from Debian - with the Python 2 death this year, Python 2 only packages were heavily scrubbed in Debian.  These changes trickled down to Ubuntu, and the package was removed.

The only way to install it would be to download the package from the Bionic repositories and manually install it.  However, there is no guarantee the package will work, or that the dependencies are available, given the Great Python 2 purge that has been going on upstream in Debian.

Answer (score 2):

Mididings was [dropped from Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mididings) (and thence from Ubuntu) since Ubuntu 18.04.

You will find it in the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories, but not 20.04.

```
$ rmadison mididings    // A script that searches the repositories
 mididings | 0~20101119-2build1 | precise/universe | source, all
 mididings | 0~20120419~ds0-4   | trusty/universe  | source, all
 mididings | 0~20120419~ds0-5   | xenial/universe  | source, all
 mididings | 0~20120419~ds0-6   | bionic/universe  | source, all
```

Comment: Forgive me whie I also write an answer that expands on this and the reasons for removal.

Answer (score 2):

this is how I installed mididings on ubuntu 20.04 :
tried it on a ubuntu studio live usb, so I guess this should be all the packages one needs.

```
#install mididings on ubuntu 20.04

#get pip2

sudo apt install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py


sudo python2 get-pip.py

#install dependencies

sudo pip2 install decorator

sudo pip2 install cython

sudo apt install liblo-dev 

sudo apt-get install python-dev

sudo pip2 install pyliblo


sudo apt install  libjack-jackd2-dev

sudo apt install libasound2-dev

sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev

sudo apt install build-essential

sudo apt install   libboost-thread-dev 

sudo apt install libboost-python1.67.0 

#make a symlink for libboost_python


sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python27.so.1.67.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so


#get mididings source and compile it


sudo apt install git

git clone https://github.com/dsacre/mididings.git

cd mididings

sudo python2.7 setup.py install

#clean our symlink

sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so
```

hope this helps

rik

Comment: big thanks for this! i was pulling my hair out for the issue with libboost.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it installed in Ubuntu 21.10 with your instructions :) In Ubuntu 21.10 I also had to add the focal universe apt repo to be able to download that version of boost, which still included Python 2 support (I added `deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, where you should change `es` with the country you're in.

Comment: I must solemnly confess that I have installed mididings on python3 and debian12 right now. So it IS possible! It is, but do not ask me how? Simply SOMEHOW! I tried to install EVERYthing except Microsoft Windows... UUfff...